# what is the maximum level of reputation earned per day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

is there any limits on maximum number of reputations earned per day. if there is limit, what happens if the user crosses that limit. Will it be given on the next day or it will cancelled ?

Comment: First of all: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation and have you tried to do some own research for the other questions?

Answer (score 3):

There is a daily reputation cap of 200 reputation a day.

Reputation for accepted answers and won bounties are exempt from this cap - there is no limit to how much reputation can be gained from those in a day.

Reputation that would have been gained if not for the cap is not refunded on following days.

The full details are available on:

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)